# Is it possible to deserialize derived class as base not knowing exact class type?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, deserialization

I am using xml serializator as below:

```
    public T Deserialize<T>(string model, string rootElementName = null) where T : new()
    {
        var xmlRootAttribute = GetXmlRootAttribute(rootElementName);

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), xmlRootAttribute);

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        {  
            streamWriter.WriteLine(model);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            return (T) serializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }
    }
```

There is one generic place (involving data validation) in my system where I don't need to know exact class type and in fact I know only about base class. Is it possible to deserialize this xml document using as type parameter base class? What if T is in fact a `List<DerivedClass>`? Invoked as:

```
    protected List<T> Deserialize<T>(string model) where T : new()
    {
        return XmlHelper.Deserialize<List<T>>(model, RootElementName);
    }
```

Comment: you cant `downcast` base class to derived class..

Comment: you can use `interface`..

Comment: no offense guys but those comments are less then useful... after calling new XmlSerializer(typeof(DerivedClass), xmlRootAttribute).Serialize(xmlWriter, model) ;this works: Deserialize<DerivedClass>(string model) ; but this returns null: Deserialize<BaseClass>(string model), so I am asking is anyone knows if there is a way to make it work assuming I need only reference to base class?